# Box Html Css Fix For the Noob

Tags: html, css

Sorry guys.
I am new here and I just got stuck in this.

I have attached a weblink to the picture and code for css.

Everything the same. 
Except when the label is a single line, the box shrinks.
I have given fixed width and height to it but still not working.

[image]

```css
.product-box {
  background: #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #dcdcdc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.product-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.product-label {
  width: 80px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-label-style {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Rubik-Medium;
  color: $app-greyish-brown;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-box" ng-click='ctrl.productClick()'>
  <div class="product-image" ng-transclude>
  </div>
  <div class="product-label">
    <label class="product-label-style">Commercial Vehicles</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-box" ng-click='ctrl.productClick()'>
  <div class="product-image" ng-transclude>
  </div>
  <div class="product-label">
    <label class="product-label-style">Vehicles</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping @mplungjan !

Answer (score 1):

Wrap those ".product-box" to some div, let's name it .wrapper and then:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="product-box" ng-click='ctrl.productClick()'>
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="product-box" ng-click='ctrl.productClick()'>
  ...
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.product-label {
  width: 80px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hey guys,
Thanks for the help.

I found the solution to it from a friend of mine.
Overflow hidden was it!